# How to run java service as a non-root user on CentOs 6

Tags: linux, shell, centos, scripting

I have a script that starts a Java application as a service on CentOS 6:

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: - 80 20

SERVICE_NAME=cn4server
PATH_TO_JAR=/usr/local/share/myserver/cn4server.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/usr/local/share/myserver/cn4server-pid
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

It works well, but it runs as a root.

How can I change the script to run the Java application on behalf of another user?

Comment: Is this an init script, to go in `/etc/init.d`?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: The best option for me is to run the script as root while the script itself launches java server as non-root user. Is it possible to do so using simple means?

Comment: You could use `su` in init-script. As script is running as root, it will work without password.

Comment: I had a look at other init scripts, they use `start-stop-daemon`. Note carefully the option `--user` does not change user. You need `--chuid` to change user.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was:

`crontab` for a "non-root user" with the line:

```
@reboot /usr/local/share/myserver/cn4server.sh restart
```

It works fine, although it's a workaround.

Comment: Explain: how does this change the user that it is running as.